# Drupal user one off settings

Tags: users, organic-groups

I am putting together a complex Drupal user driven website. One thing I need to accomplish early on is to put users into groups as they register.

**Can anyone tell me how I can get them to register particular details which they will not be able to amend in the future?** Such data as the users gender etc....?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For the user groups, use the [auto assign role module](http://drupal.org/project/autoassignrole) and you could use [content profile](http://drupal.org/project/content_profile) and [CCK](http://drupal.org/project/cck) to create profile fields that the user can fill in.  You could use the content permissions module that's a part of CCK to allow a user to create a profile but not to edit certain fields once they've been created.